# Why does my pthread_cond_signal not immediately wake a blocked thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

I'm writing a multithreaded program where an auxiliary thread runs after a condition is met, i.e., a certain number of elements existing in a data structure.

```c
void*
gc_thread_handler(void *arg) {
    while (!done) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(gc.mutex));
        while (!gc.collect && !done) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&(gc.cond), &(gc.mutex));
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(gc.mutex));
        rcgc_activate();
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I block on the waiting thread until it receives a signal sent by the following function.

```c
void *
gc_alloc(size_t sz) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(gc.mutex));
    // ...
    gc.num_chunks++;
    if (gc.num_chunks > MAX_CHUNKS) {
        gc.collect = true;
        pthread_cond_signal(&(gc.cond));
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(gc.mutex));
    return ptr;
}
```

For some reason, however, it seems as if the signal does not immediately wake up the sleeping thread; the signals are repeatedly issued (because `gc_alloc` is repeatedly called). Eventually, the waiting thread *does* wake up and call `gc_activate`, but I don't really understand why it does not wake immediately.

MRE:

gc.h:

```c
#ifndef RCGC_H
#define RCGC_H

#define RCGC_OWALLOC(ptr, sz) (rcgc_owalloc((void **) (ptr), (sz)));
#define RCGC_ASSIGN(dest, src) (rcgc_assign((void **) (dest), (void **) (src)));

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct rcgc_allocation {
    void                   *data;
    struct rcgc_allocation *next;
    size_t                  counter;
    bool                    is_free;
};

// Reference counted gc.
struct rcgc {
    struct rcgc_allocation *head;
    struct rcgc_allocation *tail;

    int num_chunks;
    bool collect;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
};

void rcgc_init(void);
void *rcgc_alloc(size_t sz);
void *rcgc_owalloc(void **dest, size_t sz);
void rcgc_assign(void **dest, void **src);
void rcgc_activate(void);

#endif // RCGC_H
```

gc.c

```c
#include "rcgc.h"

#define MAX_CHUNKS 1000

struct rcgc gc;

static struct rcgc_allocation *rcgc_search(void *ptr);

void
rcgc_init(void) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&(gc.mutex), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(gc.cond), NULL);
    gc.head = gc.tail = NULL;
    gc.num_chunks     = 0;
    gc.collect        = false;
}

void *
rcgc_alloc(size_t sz) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(gc.mutex));
    struct rcgc_allocation *node = calloc(1, sizeof(struct rcgc_allocation));
    // Add to linked list.
    if (gc.head == NULL) {
        gc.head = gc.tail = node;
        gc.head->next = gc.tail->next = NULL;
    } else {
        gc.tail->next = node;
        gc.tail       = node;
    }

    // Now assign the ptr data.
    void *ptr     = calloc(1, sz);
    node->data    = ptr;
    node->is_free = false;
    node->counter = 1;

    // If we allocate more than enough chunks, send the signal.
    gc.num_chunks++;
    if (gc.num_chunks > MAX_CHUNKS && !gc.collect) {
        gc.collect = true;
        pthread_cond_signal(&(gc.cond));
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(gc.mutex));
    return ptr;
}

void *
rcgc_owalloc(void **dest, size_t sz) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(gc.mutex));
    // Determine where it exists in the tree.
    if (dest == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        struct rcgc_allocation *old_node = rcgc_search(*dest);
        if (old_node != NULL) {
            old_node->counter--;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(gc.mutex));
        return rcgc_alloc(sz);
    }
}

void
rcgc_assign(void **dest, void **src) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(gc.mutex));

    // If "dest" is already in the tree, find it and decrement its ref ctr.
    if (dest != NULL) {
        struct rcgc_allocation *dest_alloc = rcgc_search(*dest);
        if (dest_alloc != NULL) {
            dest_alloc->counter--;
        }
    }

    // If we cannot find the source, then it does not exist.
    struct rcgc_allocation *src_alloc = rcgc_search(*src);
    src_alloc->counter++;
    *dest = *src;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(gc.mutex));
}

void
rcgc_activate(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(gc.mutex));
    for (struct rcgc_allocation *curr = gc.head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        if (curr->counter == 0 && !curr->is_free) {
            free(curr->data);
            curr->data    = NULL;
            curr->is_free = true;
            gc.num_chunks--;
        }
    }
    gc.collect = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(gc.mutex));
}

static struct rcgc_allocation *
rcgc_search(void *ptr) {
    for (struct rcgc_allocation *curr = gc.head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        if (ptr == curr->data) {
            return curr;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "rcgc.h"

extern struct rcgc gc;

static bool done = false;

void*
rcgc_thread_handler(void *arg) {
    while (!done) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(gc.mutex));
        while (!gc.collect && !done) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&(gc.cond), &(gc.mutex));
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(gc.mutex));
        rcgc_activate();
    }
    return NULL;
}

int
main(void) {
    rcgc_init();
    pthread_t pid;
    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, rcgc_thread_handler, NULL);

    // Create a few arbitrary allocations and assignments.
    int *arr1 = rcgc_alloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    int *arr2 = NULL;

    // Do something for a while...
    double val = 0;
    while (val < 1) {
        val += 0.0001;
        arr1 = RCGC_OWALLOC(&arr1, sizeof(int));
        RCGC_ASSIGN(&arr2, &arr1);
    }

    done = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&(gc.cond));
    pthread_join(pid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue is likely in code not shown. What sets `gc.collect` to `false`? Are there any other threads that could be calling `pthread_cond_wait` and consuming the wakeup?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz there are only two threads alive at any time. The auxiliary thread is the one that goes to sleep, and the main thread signals it to wake up. When it is signaled (when the main thread sends the signal), it sets that flag to false.

Comment: Although "signal" is in its name, `pthread_cond_signal()` is not well characterized as sending a signal to a thread.  The thing receiving the signal is best understood as the CV itself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That’s a good point. In that case, then, the condition variable (inside thread B, the auxiliary thread) receives the signal.

Comment: Also, the flag (gc.collect) is set to “true” when thread A signals the condition variable. From there, thread B calls another function which acquires the lock, does some stuff, and resets that flag to false.

Comment: **If** the auxilliary thread is, in fact, waiting on the CV when the CV is signaled, then the most likely reasons for a delay before it proceeds to `rgc_activate()` would be that (i) it has to wait to (re)acquire `gc.mutex` or (ii) the `while` condition is still satisfied when it is evaluated.  Of course, any signals the CV receives *before* the auxiliary thread starts waiting on it provoke no action then or ever.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The former is correct—I wait on thread B until thread A issues the signal. Before it issues the signal, though, it sets the flag to true. Thread B is the ONLY thread that can set the flag to false (which occurs immediately before activate() returns). What I don’t really understand is why thread A gets to reacquire the lock over and over again before thread B even gets a chance to invoke activate().

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thread A is inside a while loop that is only two lines long. It adds a value to a thread-safe data structure, meaning it acquires the lock. Do you think it’s a priority issue, or is it just because the loop is so small it simply has time to add more values to the data structure before B can call activate()?

Comment: @TheProgrammer, to slightly recast David's opening comment, key details contributing to the observed behavior reside in code that has not been presented.  Without a [mre], there's not much more we can say than we already have said.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's true... I added the rest of the code as an MRE. I tried to remove as much extra code as possible to condense it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, among them:

- There is a data race involving `main.c`'s static variable `done`.  Since it is not atomic, both the original and the auxiliary thread access it, and at least one of the accesses is a write, all accesses to it must be synchronized.  The easiest way to resolve that would probably be to just make it `_Atomic` to remove the need for synchronization.
- `void *` can be viewed as a generic pointer, but `void **` *is not* a generic double pointer.  There is no such thing in C.  As a result, your `RCGC_OWALLOC` and `RCGC_ASSIGN` macros set the stage for undefined behavior of `rgc_owalloc()` and `rgc_assign()`.  Most casts for other than arithmetic reasons are semantically incorrect.  C provides automatic conversions in most situations where converting is sensible at all.
- `rcgc_thread_handler()` releases the mutex before calling `rcgc_activate()`, but `rcgc_activate()` immediately attempts to reacquire it.  It is very likely to succeed immediately under many systems' default scheduling policies, but it is not *certain* to do so.  It is possible for another thread swoop in and acquire the mutex first.  Any number of times.
- Similarly, `rcgc_owalloc()` releases the mutex immediately before calling `rgc_alloc()`, which immediately attempts to reacquire the mutex.  Again, this leaves a crack for other threads to get in and run for an arbitrary amount of time.
- the main thread does not ensure that the GC thread has reached its CV wait before it starts signaling the CV.  It's ok to signal a CV that has no waiters, but such signals don't do anything.  **This is a plausible explanation for the GC thread to run `rcgc_activate()` fewer times than the main thread signals the CV.**
- the main thread spends almost all its time holding the mutex locked, and in particular, each time it releases the mutex, it very soon attempts to acquire it again.  As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75643181/2402272) explains, with the default scheduling policy of most systems, if a thread attempts to reacquire a mutex soon enough after releasing it, it is pretty likely to seize it before any other thread trying to acquire it can do.  **This is also a plausible explanation for the GC thread to run `rcgc_activate()` fewer times than the main thread signals the CV.**

Answer (score 1):

> What I don’t really understand is why thread A gets to reacquire the lock over and over again before thread B even gets a chance to invoke activate()

That is normal behavior under the default scheduling policies of most workstation/server/mobile-device operating systems. Those systems are designed with the goal of maximizing utilization of the platform's CPUs when multiple different applications are competing for resources. Under that assumption it makes sense for the scheduler to minimize the number of context switches. Superfluous context switches would use CPU time that otherwise could have been used by an application.

When there's competition for a a mutex, the scheduler will tend to award it to a thread whose time slice has not yet expired—a thread that already is running on a CPU—instead of prematurely kicking that thread (or any other thread) off it's CPU so that it can wake up some other thread that's been awaiting the lock.

There's a name for the outcome that you are seeing. It's called "starvation." The best way to avert starvation is to minimize contention for locks. Re-architect the program so that it's very rare for any thread to ever have to actually wait when it wants to acquire a mutex. Make sure that no thread ever holds ownership of a mutex for any longer than it takes to update a few variables.

---

On the other hand: If you are dedicating the platform to a single application, then it could make sense to choose an alternative scheduling policy or an alternative "real-time" operating system that will give you more control of how the threads are scheduled.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the OP's comment to which this answer is addressed is actually characteristic of the problem.  That is, I'm not yet sure whether both threads are in fact contending for the mutex, such that scheduler behavior factors in at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Both threads *should* contend for the mutex—thread B acquires the lock to invoke activate(). In this case, thread A should not alter the data structure for obvious reasons…

Comment: You have more insight into your code than we do, @TheProgrammer.  Feel free to point out where you think that contention would occur.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, now I’m somewhat second-guessing myself. When thread A issues the signal on the CV held by thread B, thread A still has the lock, right? I imagine this means that thread B must wait until A releases the lock to proceed. When it finally does (one line later), B unlocks the mutex from the CV and attempts to call activate(), which requires the lock. I wonder if I should just remove the locks from activate()’s definition and have it unlock only after invoking activate()…

Comment: @TheProgrammer, the key question with regard to contention for the mutex is whether or when thread A attempts to *reacquire* the mutex.  No, thread B does not necessarily acquire it immediately upon the CV it is waiting on being signaled.  Yes, if thread A attempts to acquire it again very soon after releasing it, then it may succeed before thread B gets it, as this answer describes.  How likely that is to explain your issue is what I'm presently trying to determine.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I’m 99% certain that what you’re describing is correct. Perhaps I just need to minimize my critical section code.

Comment: I’m even more convinced because both owalloc and assign require the lock, and they’re called one after another.

Comment: No, @TheProgrammer, if this explains your issue then what you need is to do *more* work *outside* critical sections.  Or not worry about it if you don't have to.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yep, that’s true. I guess I could also create a second lock and condition variable that thread A waits on until thread B finishes. In other words, if A signals B’s CV, A sets a flag (gc.collect……..), that it waits on, until B is done with activate().

Comment: @TheProgrammer, John said, "...more work outside critical sections..." Yes. One approach often used in multi-threaded programs is to do _speculative_ work. Not saying this will fit _your_ application, but the idea is (1) some thread, locks a lock only just long enough to take a snapshot of some shared data. Then (2) it releases the lock, and does work on its own local copy. (3) it re-locks the lock and checks to see if the original snapshot still is valid. If so, then it pushes results out to shared variables and releases the lock, but if not, it discards the work, and goes back to try again.

Comment: Yes, @TheProgrammer, that could do it.  But if there is only one thread other than the GC thread anyway, then it would be better to just perform the GC synchronously.  This is roughly what the Boehm GC does.  And it can work in a multithreaded environment too -- GC gets performed in the threads that perform allocation  / deallocation, not in a separate thread.

Comment: @JohnBollinger do you mean to just have the main thread invoke the GC instead of delegating to a separate thread?

Comment: OTOH, if you find that two threads are _always_ operating in sync with each other—if thread A always does its thing, and then as soon as it's finished, thread B takes over—then that _could_ be a sign that you'd be better off with a single thread that does both things.

Comment: Yes, @TheProgrammer, that's what I mean by "synchronously".